# Google Maps - visitor generated marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I found a WP extension for adding a Google Maps plugin which supports visitor-generated markers.

http://www.wpgmaps.com/visitor-generated-markers-add-on/

Does anyone know how this is done using GoogleMaps JavaScript API v3?

Thanks already!

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you look at their demo map, it's using Google Maps API to add their markers.  See their JS at http://www.wpgmaps.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-maps-pro/js/core.js?ver=5.34p

And you can see they're loading the markers data from an XML file, e.g. at http://www.wpgmaps.com/wp-content/uploads/wp-google-maps/6markers.xml?u=9690

So when you submit their form to add a marker, it's saving it server-side into that XML file.  This will be WPGmaps' own server-side code for doing that.  And it's their own javascript that loads in that XML file, loops over it and calls the Google Maps functions for adding markers and infowindows.